# Why are non-boolean values not implicitly converted in boolean expressions?

Tags: implicit-conversion, julia, boolean-expression

Some programming languages evaluate

```
5 == true
```

to true, or allow

```
if 5 then expr
```

by converting 5 to a bool.

Julia does not. Why?

Comment: One reason I can think of is to avoid the classic mistake `if a=1` instead of `if a ==1` (in the first case, the condition is valued to 1, thus always true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `==` is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

In Julia, `true`, when converted to an integer, becomes `1`, and so `1 == true`. If `true == 5`, then in order for `==` to preserve transitivity, that would imply that `1 == 5`

Comment: I didn't know that `1 == true` is valid and evaluates to `true` in Julia! I'm kind of disappointed, and I now realise that my answer is incorrect... `:'(`

Comment: A reasonable point. So there is a conversion done, but it's the promotion of the boolean, not the demotion of the integer.
Yet, bool(5) -> true and convert(Bool,5) -> true.

Comment: The general rule is that types should be promoted to the larger one. I'm not quite sure why bool(5) == true.

Comment: The `bool` function should just be deprecated and then deleted. The conversion to `Bool` should be fixed. There's unfortunately, no way to do that without potentially breakings some code.

Comment: Related issue on JuliaLang/julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10712.

Comment: I think the reason `bool(5) == True`, e.g. in python, is precisely to get `if 5: ...` to work, as you can't do `if 5` in Julia you needn't define Bool(5).

Answer (score 0):

Because they're not the same.

More verbosely.
The concepts of a number and a truth value (boolean) are distinct. There is no conceptual mapping between these two things. When a computer is creating a mapping it's giving each of the boolean states an **arbitrary** numeric symbol. There is nothing in mathematics that states what number the token `FALSE` should map to. A quite reasonable mapping would be:

1. FALSE
2. TRUE
3. FileNotFound

There is a common *computing* convention that `FALSE` should map to zero and `TRUE` should map to one ... or minus one ... or something else ... or everything else. But this isn't a hard rule, and has **no** basis in mathematics.

This isn't limited to Julia.